# Аналог папки lib из Eclipse в IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, java-ee

Решил поработать над JavaEE приложениями (Tomcat 8.5) в IntelijIDEA.
В Eclipse была такая замечательная папочка **lib**:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В нее можно было закинуть JAR именно для этого проекта, да  и в будущем он (JAR-ник) просто таскается с проектом. Не надо пути менять, что удобно.
Вопрос в том, как сделать такую же папку в **IntelliJ IDEA**? Или что-нибудь подобное по функционалу такой папке?
***P.s.*** В Eclipse папка создавалась **автоматически** и весь проект ее видел сразу.

Comment: А собирать проект руками? А так структура ресурсов проекта диктуется сервером и app-сервером, а никак не IDE

Comment: Какая система сборки для проекта?

Comment: @Tachkin это ясно, просто почему на том же сервере в eclipse есть такая папка, а тут нет. При том, что нет ни maven, ни gradle и это автоматически сгенерированный проект.

Comment: В IDEA втроенный мавен, кажется, так что все же это мавен архетип, всего скорее.

Comment: Хех, интересно. Благодарю за мысль. Но отсюда следует, что такую весьма удобную папку, мне не получиться запихнуть в проект?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оказалось, решение очень легкое и элегантное:

1. Идем в Project Structure:
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
2. Дальше в Libraries:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

3. Жмем "**+**" -> Java -> выбираем нашу папку lib в проекте. 
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
4. Если папка лежит по правильному пути (/WEB-INF/lib), то Tomcat сам все найдет.